# difftime does not work when the time difference is huge in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to convert the time difference into quantities with the same unit in R. However, when the time difference is huge, the `difftime()` function does not work. Here is a MWE:

```
library(lubridate)

as.integer(difftime(ymd_hms("2016-02-23 16:14:56"), ymd_hms("2015-06-13 00:00:00"), "mins"))
# [1] 255
```

The code did work when the time difference is within 1 hour:

```
as.integer(difftime(ymd_hms("2015-06-13 00:59:00"), ymd_hms("2015-06-13 00:00:00"), "mins"))
# [1] 59
```

Anyone has advice on this? Thank you!

Comment: Add `units = "mins"`, the third argument is for `tz = `. So the difference is 255 days. If you take it out of `as.integer()`, it becomes a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The 255 you see is the difference in days. If you specify `units = 'mins'`, you will see the results in minutes.

```
difftime(ymd_hms("2016-02-23 16:14:56"), ymd_hms("2015-06-13 00:00:00"), units = "mins")
```